# How to vary the WHERE clause of a linq to entity statement?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, where-clause

I am using entity framework 6.1.2 with Visual Studio 2012. Right now I have code to this effect, where `min`, `max` and `item.value` are doubles:

```
If Not Double.IsNegativeInfinity(min) AndAlso Not Double.IsPositiveInfinity(max) Then
    query = From item In query
        Where item.value >= min AndAlso item.value <= max
        select item
ElseIf Not Double.IsNegativeInfinity(min) Then
    query = From item In query
        Where item.value >= min
        select item
ElseIf Not Double.IsPositiveInfinity(max) Then
    query = From item In query
        Where item.value <= max
        select item
End If
```

The example provided is simple, but there are several instances with complex queries that I have to effectively write three times because entity framework doesn't know what to do with infinite doubles.

What I would like to do is replace all that with:

```
query = From item In query
    Where in_range(item.value, min, max)
    select item
```

Such that `in_range` expands to whatever is necessary.

Is this possible and if so, how can I do this?

**Edit:** Some of my queries are more complicated and involve using `in_range` on the result of some subquery or on differently named columns.

For example, it might be used to find all widgets where the sum of the widget's components weigh less than 20.

It might used more than once but in different columns, for example to find rectangles with heights in one range and widths in another.

I probably should have been more clear but `item` and `value` are merely placeholders for things that could really be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
I misunderstood the original question of dealing with +/- infinity. Instead of writing three queries you could test the min/max and if either returns infinity then set them equal to [Double.MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Double.MinValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and then execute the query.

Comment: The reason for writing the same thing three times is that entity framework can't handle infinite doubles. I currently use three separate cases that handle each possible combination of infinities but this is tedious.

Comment: @Whanhee Sorry, I misunderstood what you were getting at. I edited my answer with some links to MSDN docs. It's still somewhat laborious but you could use an if statement to test for infinites and set the offender to either double.MaxValue or double.Minvalue before using the variables in your query

Comment: The obvious solution escapes me as I mess around with expression trees. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Whanhee No problem, I'm glad that worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using C# synax, but you can express Linq queries using the extension methods and manipulate them that way:

```
void InRange<T>(IQuerable<T> query, Double value, Double min, Double max) {
    if( Double.IsNegativeInfinity(value) ) return query.Where( i => i.value >= min);
    if( Double.IsPositiveInfinity(value) ) return query.Where( i => i.value <= max );
    return query.Where( i => i.value >= min && i.value <= max );
}
```

Then used like so:

```
query = InRange( query, item.value, min, max ).Select( i => i.whatever );
```

Converting this to VB should be straightforward.

Comment: I don't think that will quite work. Some queries would use `in_range` on differently named columns or on values returned by subqueries. I would like to somehow generalize this.

Comment: I have edited my question to provide maybe some more relevant detail.